# html to xhtml conversion in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, xhtml

I have disigned a web page using jquery and html now I wish to convert the same webpage to xhtml form i've tried doing it myself but I am not getting desired results..i'm postin part of my code for your reference..
can anybodybody tell me where i am going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:head>
<title>Portal</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zoombox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/ui.all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/ui.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#switcher').themeswitcher();});
    $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#settingsDialog").dialog("open");
            });
            });
     $(function () {
     $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
     $(".selectable").bind('click', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('selected').toggleClass('ui-state-default');
     var str=$(this).attr('id');
     $("#p_"+str).toggle();
     });

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $("#settingsDialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width:670,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Save: function () {

               });


                $(this).dialog("close");

            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close")
            }
        },
        close: function () {}
    });
     });

    </script>

    </h:head>


    <h:body>
    <div class="demo">
    <div><label id="hdrlogo" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><label  id="img"></label><button id="btn" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Customize"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span></button>
    </label></div>

    <div id="settingsDialog" title="Settings">
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#set1">Resize Pane</a></li>
    <li><a href="#set2">Select Theme</a></li>
    <li><a href="#set3">Add/Remove Widgets</a></li>

    <li><a href="#set4">Select Layout</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="set1">
<input type="range" id="scroller" min="29" max="60" value="29" /><input type="text" id="size"/>
        </div>
       <div id="set2">
           <div id="switcher" class="ui-state-default"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="set3">
        <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="selectable ui-state-default" id="0">Feeds</li>
    <li class=" selectable ui-state-default" id="1">Pipelined Stages</li>
    <li class="selectable ui-state-default" id="2">Qualifying</li>
            </ol>
       </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
   </h:body>
  </html>
```

Comment: let me get this right.. so you wanna convert html to xhtml, using jquery... ? And I don't see your javascript in the html.

Comment: ya i am sorry i'll just re-paste my code.

Comment: Are you asking how you can use jQuery in an XHTML document? (Rather then using jQuery to perform the conversion)? Browsers act significantly differently in XML mode; I'd be surprised if jQuery was compatible, let alone all of half a dozen different plugins.

Comment: As for where you are going wrong … you aren't telling us what results you get or what the desired results are (nor are you providing a working test case (e.g. on jsfiddle)).

Comment: @ Quentin yes my questions is how to use jquery code in the Xhtml document.

Answer (score -1):

There is a webpage which shows hints for doing such things: http://webdesign.about.com/od/xhtml/a/aa013100b.htm
I would suggest you paste all your javascript code in one file, so your webpage would be a lot faster and the html code would be alot easier to read !